# Android Sqlite Order by two regulators

Tags: android, sqlite, select, sql-order-by

I have an obstacle in my sqlite query. I would like to select a specific entry. 
It should be selected the one, which has the latest date. if multiple entries have the same date, it should be picked the one with the highest ID.

Current query:

```
 String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_BODY + " ORDER BY " + COLUMN_DATE + " DESC LIMIT 1";
```

**NOTE:** `COLUMN_DATE` domain is `long`.

So currently the one with the latest date is picked. How to upgrade it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_BODY + " ORDER BY " + COLUMN_DATE + " DESC, " + COLUMN_ID + " DESC LIMIT 1";
```